# eclipse c/c++ CDT build just one file

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm doing a C++ project with eclipse CDT but It takes a lot of time building all the source files.

I'd prefer just build the one source file which I'm working with until it's correct and later go ahead to the next source file. But all the options I have seen of eclipse (Make project and Build all), work over all the source files of the project.

Is there any easy way to build just one or two source files in eclipse CDT?

Thank you!

Comment: Based on some Google searches, people seem to be using plugins or Makefiles for that. See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/39953/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/sfilecompileecl/ for possible plugins.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It was much easier than expected.

1. Deselect **Project -> Build Automatically**
2. Right click on the file you want to build
3. Click on **Build Selected File(s)**.

Source: http://www.cesareriva.com/single-file-compile-in-eclipse-cdt/

Comment: doesn't work for me either, it's Oxygen.3a. After I did step 1, the build selected file option is in grey (disabled)

Comment: Works here, Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0). I'd suggest step 4 to do a shortcut: `Window->Preferences->General->Keys`, select `Build Selected File(s)` and under `Binding:` type your shortcut, for example `Shift+F10`.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using makefile project. Simply add '-j n' (n specifies the concurrent job number) into your make parameter.

open 'project properties' -> 'C/C++ Build' -> 'Behavior'(page label) -> 'Build (incremental build'(edit box)

e.g. change it to '-j 3 all', will tell make to compile 3 files at same time.

Of course, make will detect file dependencies to decide whether the files can be compiled at same time.

cheers

Comment: I think eclipse C++ project is using 'make' internally. So you can check the parameters even if it's not a makefile project.

Comment: make -j is for parallel building. Nothing to do with the question...