# Speeding edit-compile cycle in Eclipse CDT: Build file in active editor first then entire project

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am running a vendor IDE on Windows that's a fancy fork of Eclipse CDT.  (Actually the same behavior is desired in several such vendor IDEs).

When editing C++ code, I like to make a few changes, then check for build errors before continuing to code.  I'd like to catch anything in the project that I've broken, but most of the issues are going to happen when compiling the file I'm editing.

Building the whole project is SLOW, as it first runs through makefiles for each dependent static library and does a few seconds of file timestamp checking to prove it's up to date (even though static libraries aren't needed until the link step, which I'm unlikely to reach due to compile errors).  [Building the single file from context menu "Build selected file(s)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20023727/103167) is very fast and productive.

Is there any way to bind a hotkey to the sequence "**Build selected file(s), then if and only if that succeeded, build the project**"?  Even better if it can build a corresponding implementation file when I'm editing a header (using the same logic as "Toggle Source/Header").